# How to use nested dictionary to draw networkx tree graph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, networkx

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{
        "dashboard": {
            "dashboard": {
                "data": {
                    "data": {
                        "content": {}
                    }
                },
            }
        },
        "docs": {
            "docs": {
                "content": {},
                "analytics": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to use this dictionary to draw a networkx tree graph. As there are multiple roots, can I draw multiple graphs instead of one? For example, two separate graphs for 'dashboard and 'docs'. Another problem I am facing that I can't use the dictionary directly to the networkx. Till now I found readwrite.json_graph.tree_graph() can read such dictionary object and generate graph. But the problem is I need to change the format. How can I make the previous dictionary to something like below:

```
    {
        {
        "id": "dashboard", 
        "children":[{
            "id": "dashboard",
            "children":[{
                "id": "data",
                "children":[{
                    "id": "data",
                    "children":[{
                        "id": "content"
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }
        {
        "id": "docs",
        "children":[{
            "id": "docs",
            "children":[{
                "id": "content",
                "id": "analytics"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }
```

I have tried this code to change the format:

```
        def translate(d, p, r):
            for k, v in d.items():
                # if k not in p:
                r = {
                    'id': k,
                    'children' if isinstance(v, dict) else None: translate(v, p, r)
                }
            return r

        result = translate(all_items, has_parent, r={})
        return result
```

Comment: how does the graph relate to your code? I don't get the relational structure you are trying to capture from your nested dictionaries (networkx works good with a dictionary of dictionaries, not several layers of dictionaries) and the graph doesn't represent your dictionary ("dashboard" is missing and "hybrid" doesn't exist).

Comment: the graph is just a sample. the graph shows the path of the call.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the structure of your original dictionary, you build the labeling as you create the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools as it
d, c, d1 = {}, it.count(1), {}
g = nx.Graph()
data = {'dashboard': {'dashboard': {'data': {'data': {'content': {}}}}}, 'docs': {'docs': {'content': {}, 'analytics': {}}}}
def build_graph(g, v, p=None):
   for a, b in v.items():
      if a not in d:
         d[a] = next(c)
      g.add_node(d[a])
      if p is not None:
         g.add_edge(p, d[a])
      build_graph(g, b, p=d[a])

for a, b in data.items():
   build_graph(g, {a:b})   
   d1.update({y:x for x, y in d.items()})
   d = {}

nx.draw(g, labels=d1, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]